# Laravel scope in Model with Relation not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a table called `owners` that is a list of store owners, and I would like to query this table with its relation `stores` and get the distance the store is from the user. For now the user location is hard coded, but I plan to pass that in to the Query Scope if I can get it working. Any tips are much appreciated, thank you!

```
<?php class Owner extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'owners';    

public function scopeDistance($query) {

    $lat = '45.529999';
    $lng = '-122.680000';

    return $query->select(DB::raw("*,
                          ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( lat ) )
                            * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                            sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
            ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat]);

}

public function stores()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Store','store_id')->Distance();
}

public function storesDist()
{
    $lat = '47';
    $lng = '-124';
    return $this->belongsTo('Store','store_id')->select(DB::raw("*,
                          ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( lat ) )
                            * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                             ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                             sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                           ) AS distance"))
             ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat]);
}

<?php

class OwnersController extends \BaseController {


public function getStoresNearUserA()
{

 // This returns  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Distance()
 return Owner::orderBy('id')->with('stores')->get();

 }

public function getStoresNearUserB()
{

 // This works
 return Owner::orderBy('id')->with('storesDist')->get();

}
```

***********************************************UPDATED

```
RE: First solution

// app/models/BaseModel.php
<?php

class BaseModel extends Eloquent {


public function scopeDistance($query) {

    return $query->orderBy('id');

}


....app/models/Store.Php
<?php 


class Store extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'owners';


....app/models/Owner.Php
<?php 


class Owner extends \BaseModel {

    protected $table = 'owners';

    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Store','store_id')->Distance();
    }


...app/controllers/OwnerController.php  
<?php

class OwnersController extends \BaseController {



public function getStoreOwners()
{

        return Owner::orderBy('id')->with('stores')->get();
  }

...My Error :
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Distance()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in `setBindings` - `where` is the default. So just use 2nd param set to `select` and you'll be good:

```
public function scopeDistance($query, $lat, $lng) 
{    
    return $query->select(DB::raw("*,
                          ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( lat ) )
                            * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                            sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
            ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat], 'select');
}
```

You could alternatively use

```
->addBinging($lat, 'select')->addBinding($lng, 'select')->addBinding($lat, 'select');
```

which would be secure, because now, in case there are any other bindings for `select` (pretty rare, I admit, but still..) you would mess up the query.

Also mind that you can't use `Owner` model scope on the relation query like this. I suggest you define this scope in your `BaseModel`, then `Owner` and `Store` models will extend it and you will be able to use the scope in both.

Comment: Looks good thank you very much! I will confirm later this evening when I get home.